# Weighted and Probability Graph

Tags: probability, markov-process, graph-theory

I have a simple markov chain with A, B and C states. For each state I have a probability and beyond that, a value. So, for each state transition I have two informations: the probability of the transisiton to another state and a value.

I need to know the average value considering that I am trying to start from node A and finish in the node C.
I was thinking about to use Markov Chains but I have a value with the probability and I dont know whet kind of theory I can apply to find the average value on this path A -> C.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Writing $e_A$ for the value of $A$ and $e_B$ for the value of $B,$ your diagram indicates

$$\begin{aligned}
e_A &= 0.05(5+e_A) + 0.90(2+e_B) + 0.05(10)\\
e_B &= 0.50(3+e_A) + 0.50(3+e_B).
\end{aligned}$$

Solve these simultaneous linear equations for $e_A$ and $e_B.$

Comment: Ok, then what I need to do after finding the two variables?

Comment: $e_A$ is the answer to your question.